# Multiple table's multiple columns join to same table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join, inner-join

I have a query.

I have 3 table in mysql database.

I want to connect my tables with these rules, multiple table's, multiple columns join to same table one column.

MySQL example is given below. Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT
    s.*,e.* 
    , m1.m_id AS 'mid'
    , m1.m_name AS 'mname' 
    , m2.m_id AS 'bid'
    , m2.m_name AS 'bname'
    , e1.e_id AS 'tid'
    , e1.e_name AS 'tname'
    , e2.e_id AS 'topid'
    , e2.e_name AS 'topname'
    FROM s s,e e
    INNER JOIN m m1
    ON s.s_m_id = m1.m_id
    INNER JOIN m m2
    ON s.s_b_id = m2.m_id
    INNER JOIN e e1
    ON s.s_t_id = e1.e_id
    INNER JOIN e e2
    ON s.s_t_t_id = e2.e_id
    WHERE s_id =1
```

Comment: clarify your question please. How are your tables look like? what is your expected result?

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select("s.*,e.* 
    , m1.m_id AS 'mid'
    , m1.m_name AS 'mname' 
    , m2.m_id AS 'bid'
    , m2.m_name AS 'bname'
    , e1.e_id AS 'tid'
    , e1.e_name AS 'tname'
    , e2.e_id AS 'topid'
    , e2.e_name AS 'topname'");
$this->db->from("FROM s");
$this->db->join("m m1
     s.s_m_id = m1.m_id","inner");
$this->db->join("m m2
     s.s_b_id = m2.m_id","inner");
$this->db->join("e e1
    s.s_t_id = e1.e_id","inner");
$this->db->join(" e e2
    s.s_t_t_id = e2.e_id","inner");
$this->db->where('s_id','1');
$this->db->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

is your code not working? Try to remove the 'FROM' on

```
$this->db->from("FROM s");
```